# Stuck in laravel while inserting data in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to insert JSON sent by postman and want to store it in database but it is not inserting in database.I am using eloquent model to deal with database.

**here is my JSON**

```
{"mcode":"123","code":"321","title":"Mr.", "name":"sameer","mobile":"7798616828","email":"sameer@waev.in","address":"amravati","state":"maharashtra", "city":"amravati"}
```

**This is my controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\member;

class inquiryController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $member = new member;
       // $member->title=$request->title;

        $member->mcode = $request->mcode;
        $member->code = $request->code;
        $member->title = $request->title;
        $member->name = $request->name;
        $member->mobile = $request->mobile;
        $member->email = $request->email;
        $member->address = $request->address;
        $member->state = $request->state;
        $member->city = $request->city;

        $member->save();


        return "ok";

    }
}
```

**This is my model**

```
namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class member extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable=['mcode','code','title','name','mobile','email','address','state', 'city'];
}
```

Comment: Could you tell, is there any error comes while inserting?

Comment: Your model is set to only accept the name. That's why nothing else is getting inserted.

Comment: The `$fillable` array only intervene for mass insertion. Here he's setting manually his properties so it should work. We need some error message to respond to the question.

Comment: i am posting data from postman so i got "Internal server error 500" error and that's why i am unable to track the error.

Comment: I did the changes in $fillable as edited above.

Comment: In postman, you can see the preview of the response, can't you see anything from here? Is it a 500 error with no response body? In what environment are you working?

Comment: Isn't it a csrf problem?

Comment: The preview you are talking about is only like this "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: No thats not a csrf problem because I have commented verifycsrf line in kernel.php.

Comment: Make sur to have `APP_DEBUG=true` in your env file to be able to track the error

Comment: Thanks a ton @EI_Matella. Atleast I am now able to see what exactly the error is.

Comment: So what is it? ^^

Comment: I made changes in env as you suggested me and tracked error. thanks once again

Comment: Note: csrf is for security, shouldnot be commented.

Comment: but then what should i do if other devices(ios, android, webapp) are requesting to my api. how they will verify it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the accessable fields inside:

```
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'mcode' ....];
```

or do not declare this field - it will cause that you will be able to add data that arent's mass assinged (i.e. `$member->fill($data)`). It's exacly like you did in the example above.

Comment: Actually i did the same in my model like protected                                $fillable=['mcode','code','title','name','mobile','email','address','state', 'city'];   but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$fillable` variable is for mass assignment in controllers, try to use the following snippet to see if it works:

```
// App\Person.php
public class Person {
    $fillable = ['name', 'age'];
}

App\Controllers\PersonController.php
public class PersonController extends Controller {
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $data = $request->only('name', 'age'); // you can use Input::all() too
        return App\Person::create($data);
    }
}
```

Didn't modify your code because of the longitude, instead I'd used a smaller example, but it is the same idea.